# Find the residue of the given function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Find the residue of $\frac{\sin \alpha z}{z^3\sin \beta z}$ at 0, where $\alpha\neq \beta$ and $\beta\neq 0$.

I tried to use the general formula of calculating the residue but can't determine the order of pole 0 in this problem. Is it 3 or 4 or something else? Or should I write the Laurent series explicitly? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \frac{\sin{z}}{z} \to 1 \quad \text{as } z \to 0, $$
so $ \sin{\alpha z}/\sin{\beta z} \to \alpha/\beta $, which is finite by the assumptions in the question. Hence it's a pole of order $3$. Therefore to find the residue we want the coefficient of $z^2$ in the expansion of $ \sin{\alpha z}/\sin{\beta z}$ around $z=0$. We have
$$ \frac{\sin{\alpha z}}{\sin{\beta z}} = \frac{\alpha z - \alpha^3 z^3/6 + O(z^5)}{\beta z - \beta^3 z^3/6 + O(z^5)} = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\frac{1 - \alpha^2 z^2/6 + O(z^4)}{1 - \beta^2 z^2/6 + O(z^4)}, $$
and then the binomial expansion for $1/(1-w)$ then gives
$$ \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\frac{1 - \alpha^2 z^2/6 + O(z^4)}{1 - \beta^2 z^2/6 + O(z^4)} = \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \left( 1 - \frac{\alpha^2}{6}z^2 + O(z^4) \right) \left( 1 + \frac{\beta^2}{6}z^2 + O(z^4) \right) = \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \left( 1 + \frac{\beta^2-\alpha^2}{6}z^2 + O(z^4) \right) . $$
Hence the residue is 
$$ \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \frac{\beta^2-\alpha^2}{6}. $$